# com/onesignal/androidsdk/GradleProjectPlugin has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime

Tags: java, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I was working on a flutter project
I got this problem today. I only tried to build other projects in this week but didn;t touch this project and suddendly got this error

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/onesignal/androidsdk/GradleProjectPlugin has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

Comment: I am getting the same error with IONIC Capacitor